# Good programming practices

Tags: optimization, coding-style

Is there a pdf online describing good programming practices? (I'm thinking about basic things like conventions for capital letters). So far, the best document I found is this [one](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucappgu/seminars/good-practice.pdf)

Comment: [Search old questions on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-style+coding-standards) for style recommendations.

Comment: These best practises depend heavily on the used language and its paradigms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally different companies/groups have different preferences for variable naming, capitalization, white space formatting etc. There is no one single BEST way.

That being said, this might be a good starting point: http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide